# System.Beep equivalent

Tags: c#, class, system, beep

Is there any class for making sound in speakers by different tones?
System.Beep() is primitive, I can't send there frequency in double.

I want, let's say, play A sound or B# sound. I want to function call to be  like:

```
double d = 425,545;
int duration = 500;
int volume = 0.8;
f(d, duration, volume)
f(ToneClass.A, duration, volume)//or like this
```

Comment: For which version, Windows Forms, WPF, WinRT, UWP ?

Comment: It's for console program. But i'll maybe use it for WPF

Comment: Why do you need a `double` frequency value? The "A" note (according to Wikipedia) has an integer frequency.

Comment: Sure, but others are with comma. For C: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28musical_note%29

Comment: The "comma" A Notes are `13.75Hz` and `27.50Hz`, both are below the domain of the parameter, which has a lower bound of `37`, so those notes are impossible to make. But a human ear would barely be able to hear them anyway.

Comment: I meant with "comma" like: C => 391,9 Hz. I'm not into music, so I used the easiest notes, that I found.

Comment: Your ears are not double.  Well, other than having two :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer part for frequency is enough. your ears wont even notice decimal part.

```
int frq = 425;
int duration = 500;

Console.Beep(frq, duration);
```

You can see piano key frequencies from here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies

Some notes.

Use enum instead of ints. also use `Task.Delay(duration).Wait();` for rest . (by rest i mean silence notes)

You can use some formulas to calculate piano key and then key frequency instead of using large enum or large number of hard coded ints. Also you should consider note lengths. You can see them here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_value

Here is the piece of "Mountain King" by Edvard Grieg :D

```
static int GetPianoKey(string note)
{
    int key = -1;
    switch (note[0])
    {
        case 'A': key = 1; break;
        case 'B': key = 3; break;
        case 'C': key = 4; break;
        case 'D': key = 6; break;
        case 'E': key = 8; break;
        case 'F': key = 9; break;
        case 'G': key = 11; break;
    }
    if (note.Length == 2)
    {
        return key + 12*(note[1] - '0');
    }
    if (note.Length == 3)
    {
        return key + 12*(note[2] - '0') + (note[1] == 'b' ? -1 : 1);
    }
    throw new ApplicationException("Wrong note.");
}

static int GetNoteFrequency(string note)
{
    return (int) (Math.Pow(1.05946309436, GetPianoKey(note) - 49)*440);
}

static int GetTickDuration(int tempo)
{
    return 60000/tempo;
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int duration = GetTickDuration(120); // 120 bpm. duration for quarter note

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("A3"), duration / 2); // eighth note ==> duration/2
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("B3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("C3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("D3"), duration / 2);

        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("E3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("C3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("E3"), duration / 2);
        Task.Delay(duration/2).Wait(); //  eighth rest ==> duration/2

        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("D#3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("B3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("D#3"), duration / 2);
        Task.Delay(duration / 2).Wait();

        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("D3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("Bb3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("D3"), duration / 2);
        Task.Delay(duration / 2).Wait();

        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("A3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("B3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("C3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("D3"), duration / 2);

        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("E3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("C3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("E3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("A4"), duration / 2);

        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("G3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("E3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("C3"), duration / 2);
        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("E3"), duration / 2);

        Console.Beep(GetNoteFrequency("G3"), duration * 2); // half note ==> duration*2
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if there's mistake, but here's my code for Mountain King.http://www.music-scores.com/midi.php?sheetmusic=Grieg_Op46_Mountain_King_easy_pno           http://ideone.com/ph0tIa

Comment: It didn't play like intended.

Comment: you should pick `A3` in your music. not `A4`. so frequency should be 220 instead of 440.(an octave lower) also `246` for `B3` @Jump3r

Comment: @Jump3r haha nice one! ;)